# How to compare the difference between two datasets VS NULL in Python

Tags: python

I am creating a script that will compare an Excel file to a Snowflake database table. If the columns are all the same, the script will import the data from Excel and append or insert to the Snowflake table. I am testing with two identical Spreadsheets to get the script functioning - and if I understand my code properly this script should return "Sweet" if the there is no difference in the two files. However, it is returning "that's all folks!" which is the ELSE stmt. I may be misunderstanding how NONE works here so any thoughts on this would be helpful.

I also have a test file where I added a garbage columns ("blah") - to make sure the script is functioning properly. I get the same result whether I compare to the identical file or the blah file. I also tried == instead of IS in the IF stmt and I tried passing the set1 and set2 variables into the main() function but neither of those worked.

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_excel('./excel/file1.xlsx', sheet_name = 'export',index_col = 0)
file2 = pd.read_excel('./excel/file2.xlsx', sheet_name = 'export',index_col = 0)

set1 = set(file1.columns)
set2 = set(file2.columns)

def main():
    if set1.difference(set2) == None:
        print("Sweet")
    else: 
        print("that's all folks!")
main()
```

What I am looking to achieve is if the files have any difference in the columns, it should register with the function so that I can have it throw an error. If the columns match, then it's safe to pass through the function and ultimately write to Snowflake.

**Update**: Comparing `set1.difference(set2)` to `set()` instead of `None` did the trick.

Comment: Have you looked to see what `difference` is actually returning?

Comment: I took part of the code and ran it on it's own and difference shows set() - so I believe that means they are the same. I verify this by opening both spreadsheets and comparing. I also ran the same test with the spreadsheet that I removed a column from and it showed me that column as the difference.

Comment: `set()` is not the same as `None`.

Comment: ahhh... I am more used to SQL where I can compare against NULL for a conditional test. I just changed is NONE to == set() and it works perfectly! Is it just me or is NONE confusing? I read a very long post about it but obviously it's beyond my current understanding

Comment: Its the difference between an empty set & not being any kind of thing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using the `==` operator to check if the object equals None.

Python has different ways to check for emptiness, noneness or both.

Just putting an Iterable object in an `if` statement, or inside the `bool()` constructor, will yield true if the object is empty or if it is *None*:

```
myset = None
bool(myset)
False

myset = set()
bool(myset)
False

myset.add("foo")
bool(myset)
True
```

Comparing to None will only yield `True` if the variable compared is also None (assuming the object is a pure instance of set object):

```
myset = None
myset == None
True

myset == set()
False
```

To see if the object is none:

```
myset = None
myset is None
True
```

To see if the object is empty (note however that this will raise an exception if the object is None):

```
myset = set()
len(myset) == 0
True

myset = None
len(myset)
# [...]
TypeError #[...]
```

Pick what ever fits your context, but `if object` is safer IMO.